# Implement missing symbol on a shared library

Tags: c, unix, shared-libraries

I have a third-party library (let say `libfoobar.so`) that depends of another third-party library called `libutils.so`. I only have the old version of `libutils.so`, his older version is missing a symbol (exported function) that only exists in the new version.

I can code the function in a new shared library (let say `libwrapper.so`):

```c
extern "C" int missing_function() {
    return 123;
}
```

And... now?? how can "tell" to `libfoobar.so` to use this function, already tried:

- load `libwrapper.so` before `libfoobar.so`.
- using patchelf tool with `patchelf --add-needed libwrapper.so libfoobar.so`. But i get `dlopen failed: empty/missing DT_HASH in "libfoobar.so" (built with --hash-style=gnu?)`

I can not use the "new version" due compatibility reasons. There any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i solved the problem in a weird way creating a "proxy" library that wraps the functions used.

Step following the previous example:

1. open `libfoobar.so` in a hexadecimal editor and patch (change) the linking to a new shared library replacing the string `libutils.so` by `libutilx.so` (respect the character count)
2. also change the SONAME, in this example change `LIBSUTILS` by `LIBUTILX`
3. code the wrapper and compile as `libutilx.so`. C code example below
4. put in the same folder with `libfoobar.so` and DONE.

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

void *lib = dlopen("libutils.so", RTLD_LAZY);// original lib


// delegates
void *(*ORIGmalloc)(size_t size);
int (*ORIGpthread_setspecific)(pthread_key_t key, const void *value);


// functions
extern "C" void *malloc(size_t size) {
    return (*ORIGmalloc)(size_t);
}
extern "C" int pthread_setspecific(pthread_key_t key, const void *value) {
    return (*ORIGpthread_setspecific)(pthread_key_t, value);
}

// implements missing functions in libutils.so required by libfoobar.so
extern "C" const char *get_greeting_string() {
   return "Hello from libutilx.so !!";
}

extern "C" int some_number() {
   return 12345;
}


// assigns (just an example, you must check for errors)
// with the attribute "constructor" this function is called after the lib is opened
void  __attribute__((constructor)) assign_delegates() {
    *(void **) (&ORIGmalloc) = dlsym(lib, "malloc");
    *(void **) (&ORIGpthread_setspecific) = dlsym(lib, "pthread_setspecific");
}
```

To known whats functions are imported, use command line utility **objdump**. Example `objdump -T libfoobar.so` output will be:

```
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000  LIBUTILS        pthread_setspecific
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000  LIBUTILS        malloc
00000000      DO *UND*  00000000  LIBUTILS        __sF
```

cheers